# sshfs "reset by peer" after new installation of server OS

Tags: 18.04, ssh, remote-access, sshfs

I'm trying to mount a drive from my work PC to my home PC using the command below:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other home_username@home.ip:/ /mnt/home-pc
```

This command was working fine before. However, I've just re-installed the OS on my home PC. Now typing the command gives me an error "read: Connection reset by peer".

Any idea what is causing this? I can still ssh into my home PC after typing

```
"ssh-keygen -f "/home/work_username/.ssh/known_hosts" -R home.ip"
```

But somehow this sshfs still doesn't work. Both machines run Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have you tried to add debugging or increase the verbosity? `sshfs -o sshfs_debug -o debug ....`

Comment: Thanks! This shows up what the problem is and I've got it resolved. It turns out that sshfs stores the host key under a different dir from ssh so I need to re-type
    "ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R home.ip"
under root.